# SQL Query for a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m looking for a little assistance.  I have a table called equipment.  One row is an order of some type of equipment.

Here are the fields:

```
num_id     date     player_id     order_id    active    jersey    comment
BIGINT     DATE     BIGINT        BIGINT     CHAR(1)    CHAR(3)   VARCHAR(1024)
11       2018-01-01  123            1           Y       XL  
11       2018-01-01  123            2           Y       M       Purple
11       2018-01-01  123            3           Y       L       White, Red
13       2018-01-11  456            1           N       S       Yellow, Light Blue
14       2018-02-01  789            1           Y       M       Orange, Black
15       2018-02-02  101            1           Y       XL      Shield
15       2018-02-02  101            2           Y       XL      Light Green, Grey
```

I need to write a query that shows one row for each month with the columns
Month
Total Orders
Total Products ordered
And one extra column for a total count of each size sold.

Is this easy?  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  To answer people's questions below, SQL Server is the dbms. My apologies. As well, I am struggling as I don't know how to get the month from a date. And then adding the column for size counts has me baffled, but I haven't fully investigated that portion. I feel like the rest I have done individually, just never did it in one succinct query.

It looks weird here and I don't know how to add a table to stackoverflow, so I'll try to make it a little more visually appealing here:

The end goal I think would be like this:

```
Month   Total Orders    Total Products Ordered  Size Count
January   1              3                      S-0, M-1, L-1, XL-2

February  3              6                      S–1, M–2, L–1, XL–3
```

Or this:

```
Month   Total Orders    Total Products Ordered  S Count M Count L Count XL Count
January  1              3                         0       1       1       2
February 3              6                         1       2       1       3
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What would be very helpful is including designed output

Comment: So per month you want the number of distinct order IDs (three in your example) and the number of items ordered (the number of rows, I guess?). Do you know how to count? Do you know how to get the month from a date? Do you know how to count *per* xyz? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Which dbms???  The syntax is different for different dbms.  It's useless if someone answer your question, but using the wrong dbms.

Comment: To state even more the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name , your query WILL use date functions and each database has its own syntax (some are similar). So what is your Database brand ?

Comment: SQL Server is the dbms.  My apologies. I don't know how to get the month from a date.  And then adding the column for size counts has me baffled, but I haven't fully investigated that portion.  I feel like the rest I have done individually, just never did it in one succinct query.

Comment: Can you please share the expected output in table format for given data?

Comment: I've added the SQL Server tag. The exact version of SQL is even better (run `SELECT @@VERSION`)

Comment: Are there a limited number of sizes? That's the trick here - if you know what sizes exist you can just brute force it all out. Otherwise you need to pivot

Comment: I don't have an exact version currently.  It's more theoretical.  The sizes should be S,M,L,XL.

Answer (score 0):

You need `PIVOT`.

It basicly turns rows into columns, which exactly is your case.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query